# Can I use the Facebook iOS SDK to open a user's Facebook profile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have an app where users have their own profiles in my app. When user A opens user B's profile in my app, I want there to be a button user A can click that will open up the Facebook app to user B's Facebook profile. Can I do that with the Facebook iOS SDK?

Comment: yes, using B's Facbook ID You can get the Profile data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using custom url schemes. Facebooks custom url scheme is `fb://`

If you have the users facebook id or username you can pop out to the facebook app using something like `fb://profile/zuck`